# Syncfusion Winforms SfComboBox DropDownListView ItemWidth property not working

Tags: winforms, syncfusion, dropdownlistview

I am trying to change the ItemWidth property of SfComboBox.DropDownListView. My problem is appeared on picture 1. I want my output to be like in picture 2. That is why I wanted to change the DropDownListView ItemWidth. But it doesn't do anything. I have also tried SfComboBox.DropDownListView.Width property, but in vain. I cannot increase the width of SfComBox control. I have searched about this everywhere, but nowhere got the issue. Below is my Code: -

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(Int32));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));
        DataRow drow = dt.NewRow();
        drow["Id"] = 1;
        drow["Name"] = "Pakistan -> Islamabad -> Model Colony";
        dt.Rows.Add(drow);
        drow = dt.NewRow();
        drow["Id"] = 2;
        drow["Name"] = "Pakistan -> Islamabad -> Navel Colony";
        dt.Rows.Add(drow);
        drow = dt.NewRow();
        drow["Id"] = 3;
        drow["Name"] = "Pakistan -> Islamabad -> Block X";
        dt.Rows.Add(drow);
        drow = dt.NewRow();
        drow["Id"] = 4;
        drow["Name"] = "Pakistan -> Islamabad -> Block Y";
        dt.Rows.Add(drow);
        sfComboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        sfComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        sfComboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
        sfComboBox1.DropDownListView.ItemWidth = 400; //this is not working
```

Please suggest some solution.

[image]

[image]